# Pages missing on the server side only, in a Firebase/React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase-hosting

I have a little web app using Firebase and React.

Locally it runs on

```
http://localhost:3000/
```

and has a couple of subpages like:

```
http://localhost:3000/login
http://localhost:3000/manage
```

All is OK so far. Then I upload my page to the server (as I have already done a few times now), running:

```
npm run build
firebase deploy
```

I can at this point access the app on the server, as expected using some link like:

```
https://myapp.web.app/
```

But I hit problems hereafter, trying these URLs (for some subpages) in the browser:

```
https://myapp.web.app/login
https://myapp.web.app/manage
```

I get this result, showing that some pages must be missing:

```
404
Page Not Found

The specified file was not found on this website. Please check  the URL for mistakes and try again.
Why am I seeing this?

This page was generated by the Firebase Command-Line Interface.     To modify it, edit the 404.html file in your project's  configured public directory.
```

I have checked my firebase.json file that this line is present in the "hosting" section:

```
"public": "build",
```

Knowing that, is there some possible issue that an experienced Firebase/React user would immediately think about and that I may be missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is probably because you init project and set it as it is not SPA.

Set up your `firebase.json` file like this:

```
{
"hosting": {
    "target": "This is when you need target",
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Most important for SPA is `"rewrites"` section. When you open home page using browser request looks like this `example.web.app/index.html` even if you wrote `example.web.app` and when you request `example.web.app/manage` request looks like `example.web.app/menage/index.html` And in reallity you don't have this document so you need to setup hosting to rewrites all request to this one `index.html` document.

Comment: Yes. I tried and it works. Thanks a lot for pointing that out.